# How do I move a function inside a service?

Tags: angular, observable

I have this function that I use to change the value of one control, depending on the value of another control. Since I am using this function in several components, I thought I should move it to a service and call it from there. The thing is that I have to subscribe to the formControl's valuechanges. So my question is,

How do I rewrite this function, so that I can use it inside a service, without subscribing inside the service?

Here is my function:

```
  setDefault(formarray: FormArray, index: number, sourceCtrl:string, targetCtrl:string ) {
        formarray.at(index)
            .get(sourceCtrl)
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy))
            .subscribe(value => {
                if (value !== null && value !== "" && value !== undefined) {
                    formarray.at(index)
                        .get(targetCtrl)
                        .setValue(this.default);
                } else {
                    formarray.at(index)
                        .get(targetCtrl)
                        .setValue(null);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Return an observable?

Comment: If I return an observable and I unsubscribe from the returned observable, the subscription to the valuechanges completes also...? This I don't get...

Answer (score 0):

Like `jonrsharpe` said you can return an `observable`. Everywhere you unsubscribe from it, should not be an issue because each subscription will be their own.

But I see the code in the `subscribe` can be repetetive as well so maybe you can take advantage of object oriented programming.

Create a base class:

```
export class BaseFormClass() {
 setDefault(formarray: FormArray, index: number, sourceCtrl:string, targetCtrl:string ) {
        formarray.at(index)
            .get(sourceCtrl)
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy))
            .subscribe(value => {
                if (value !== null && value !== "" && value !== undefined) {
                    formarray.at(index)
                        .get(targetCtrl)
                        .setValue(this.default);
                } else {
                    formarray.at(index)
                        .get(targetCtrl)
                        .setValue(null);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

And whichever component that needs this functionality can extend `BaseFormClass`.

```
export class Component1 extends BaseFormClass implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDefault(......);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok! I see the extending class approach. Right now, the above function subscribes to the valueChanges observable and unsubscribes when my component is destroyed using the takeUntil operator. Could someone help me understand, if I return an observable and then unsubscribe from this observable, what happens with the subscription inside the function? Is it completed too? Should I call complete to this as well is some way?

Comment: if the observable completes, you don't have to call any complete function